# To show that $\underset{\alpha \in \mathcal J}{\sup}\|T_\alpha x_n - T_\alpha x\|_{W} \overset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

I am going through one paper and stuck at one point. We have $\{T_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in \mathcal{J}}$, a family of continuous linear maps from a Banach space $V$ to a normed space $W$, which is pointwise bounded. We define another norm on $V$ by $\|x\|_{2}=\|x\|_{V}+ \underset{\alpha \in \mathcal J}{\sup}\|T_\alpha x\|_{W}$. We take $(x_n)$ cauchy in $(X,\|\cdot\|_{2})$. The author says the following.

"It follows that the sequences $\{T_\alpha x_n\}$ are uniformly cauchy from which we immediately see that  $\underset{\alpha \in \mathcal J}{\sup}\|T_\alpha x_n - T_\alpha x\|_{W}  \overset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$".

So, this is what I have reach so far. The first claim that the sequences are uniformly cauchy is easy to see by the definition of $\| \cdot \|_{2}$. Also, we can see that for each $\alpha \in \mathcal J$, $T_\alpha x_n$ is cauchy in $Y$ and also $(x_n)$ is cauchy in $X$. As $X$ is complete, $(x_n)$ is convergent in $X$. Let say $x_n \to x$. It follows that $T_\alpha x_n \rightarrow T_\alpha x$  for each $\alpha$, as it is continuous. I am not getting the last point which intuitively seems correct but I am unable to write down in mathematical words.

This is what I think about it. For given $\epsilon > 0$, we can find $N$ such that for all $m,n > N$, $\underset{\alpha \in \mathcal J}{\sup}\|T_\alpha x_n - T_\alpha x_m\|_{W} < \epsilon$. Fix n and let $m \to \infty$. If I can show that $\underset{\alpha \in \mathcal J}{\sup}\|T_\alpha x_n - T_\alpha x_m\|_{W} \overset{m \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} \underset{\alpha \in \mathcal J}{\sup}\|T_\alpha x_n - T_\alpha x\|_{W}$, then I think we are done. But I am not sure how this last convergence will follow.

Comment: I think you will need the Uniform boundedness principle:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle

Comment: @rubikscube the above step is used in proving  uniform boundedness principle itself.

Comment: I apologize, I completely misread the question!

Comment: No problem. I have added few details that I miss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pass to the limit before taking the supremum, rather than afterwards. Indeed, you know that for $n,m \geq N$ as in the question and for arbitrary fixed $\alpha$,
$$\|T_\alpha x_n - T_\alpha x_m \| < \varepsilon$$
Sending $m \to \infty$ and using continuity of $T_\alpha$ you get that
$$\|T_\alpha x_n - T_\alpha x \| \leq \varepsilon.$$
Since $\alpha$ was arbitrary you can now take the $\sup$ over $\alpha$ to conclude that
for $n \geq N$,
$$\sup_{\alpha \in J} \|T_\alpha x_n - T_\alpha x \| \leq \varepsilon$$